# How to get input text value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have the following code, in mydata.jsp value of q is empty. What is the correct way to pass value of inputId to mydata.jsp?

```
<input type="text" size="25" name="inputId" id="inputId" />
```

and Jquery script as

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#inputId").autocomplete({

        source: "mydata.jsp?q="+$( "#inputId" ).val(),
        select:function(event,ui) {
            $("#hid").val(ui.item.email)
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `$( "#inputId" ).val()` as an argument to `.autocomplete()`, you're getting the initial value from that field before anything has been typed.  That would explain why it is empty.

If you use the string version of autocomplete, it can automatically add the typed value to the URL.  See the doc for the string version of `source` [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

If you want the URL for the `source` to be a dynamically generated URL, then you can also pass a function as the `source` and the code in that function can generate the URL/alternatives.  See the doc for the `source` option [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Comment: How can I pass the value of `inputId` to `mydata.jsp`?

Comment: In the [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), see the string option for the `source` property.  The autocomplete method will automatically add the current value of the typed term.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#inputId').keyup(function()
{
var str=$(this).val();
if(str!='')
{
  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"mydata.jsp",
      data:"str="+str,
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
     }

  });
}
});
```

Try like this. hope it will give you some solution.